# How to get the current position of a cell that calls a function

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have a function called `CalculateSomeNumber()`

and in Cell A1 I have it =CalculateSomeNumber()

How can I tell what the cell location is? Is there a way to somehow find out that cell A1 is the cell invoking CaulcateSomeNumber?

Comment: yes, look into [Application.ThisCell Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834969(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Ah, thank you, you save my life again @simoco, I noticed that I can get the Row/Column easily with this, but to take it a step further, would it be possible to get the rows below this current cell by using offset? Or would I have to create a new cell, and then use the offset on that cell?

Comment: yes, you could use `Application.ThisCell.Offset(1).Address`

Comment: @simoco thanks! And.. well, we're in this awkward situation where I have to accept your answer now hah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Application.ThisCell Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834969(v=office.15).aspx) like this:

```
Function CalculateSomeNumber() As String
    CalculateSomeNumber = Application.ThisCell.Address
End Function
```

**Result:**

[image]